# Building Julia on sublime text 3 gives WinError 2

Tags: sublimetext3, julia

I am very new to Julia and wanted to use Sublime Text 3.

When I try to run the simplest code, something like this happens: [image]

You can see that Julia is added to the path.

I constantly got zmq issue at the start of Sublime Text. I tweaked the windows part of IJulia settings to take care of the zmq error.

```
{
"zmq_shared_library": "C:/Users/reha/.julia/v0.5/WinRPM/deps/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/libzmq.dll",
"commands": [
    {
        "command_name": "default",
        "julia": "julia.exe",
        "julia_args": "",
        "ijulia_kernel": "C:/Users/reha/.julia/v0.5/IJulia/src/kernel.jl"
    }
]
```

However, Sublime keeps not building my .jl files. I have no issue with .py files. They work as they are supposed to. What is the problem here?

EDIT: It worked when I saved the file in the julia directory. For some reason, I failed to add Julia to the path, however you can see that it is in the path in the provided screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I found out](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/IJulia) that adding Julia to path is not enough to add Julia to path. The address of libzmq should also be added to the path.

Now Julia files work from any location.